# Obtaining Residual Deviance from cv.glmnet in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, glmnet, deviance

I'm wondering how to obtain the residual deviance from my selected logistic regression model (once lambda has been selected) so that I can compare this model with another model I'll make from dropping one of the variables to see what affect this has.

The overall goal is basically to rank the predictors in order of importance. The plan was to do this by creating models with variables dropped out to see what affect this has on the residual deviance (per df) compared to the full model.

If anyone could assist me in any way that would be great!